# Executing bat file via SAS

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sas

I was wondering if it's possible to execute a bat file i created via SAS?

Reason for this is, unfortunately I do not have admin privileges to schedule the execution of my batch file on task scheduler when I'm not logged in...I need to be logged in for the batch file to execute.

On the contrary my team schedules jobs on SAS so I was wondering if there is a command that can execute my .bat file through the same concept?

I'm happy to accept any other solutions

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always suggest using a pipe fileref when calling OS commands, this way you can capture both STDOUT and STDERR.

```
data _null_;
  infile "C: & C:\path\to\your.bat 2>&1" pipe;
  input;
  putlog _infile_;
run;
```

To explain the command:

1) First, change the drive (not necessary if SAS is on the same drive as the .bat file).  This is the `C:` part.

2) Next, execute the file (`C:\path\to\your.bat`)

3) Finally, redirect STDERR to STDOUT (the `2>&1` part).  This will show you any errors.

If you still get nothing, try executing the batch file manually using the *same* account as you use in SAS, and - on the same machine (eg where the SASApp server is hosted).  In a batch environment this may be a batch user.  In a Stored Process context it may be `sassrv` (or equivalent).

Comment: i am using sas university edition and i have an error about pipe authorization. Can u help me? Error: Insufficient authorization to access PIPE.

Answer (score 1):

```
options noxwait noxsync;
x 'path\to\your\file.bat';
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work? It successfully ran with no errors however the bat file did not execute? Should I be adding a command to the start of my .bat file?
The .bat file does execute if i double click the file though...

Comment: You can check if it worked by changing **options xwait;** then run the X command and SAS leaves the shell open for observation. For debugging add echos to your bat.